# foreach $_POST.. is this bad?

Tags: php

Is it bad practice to use use a foreach to make an array of all post data vs defining exactly what posts you are accepting?

```
class Foo { 

    function __construct()
    {
        foreach($_POST as $key => $var)
        {
            $this->post[] = $key = $var;
        } 
    }

    function bar()
    {
        echo $this->post['postdata'];
    }

}
```

vs;

```
class Foo { 

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->post = array(
          "postdata" => $_POST['postdata']
        );
    }

    function bar()
    {
        echo $this->post['postdata'];
    }

}
```

Comment: `$this->post[] = $key = $var;` probably doesn't do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no great harm in automatically processing all of POSTed fields, as long as that processing is limited to storing in a hash. Matter of fact, it can make fore a significantly easier to maintain code.

The moment you start doing something (especially system related) with that data, you need to validate.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Great input! But I kind of lost you with the hash part, can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

The only really bad practice I can find in this code is use of a global state/data. Your objects should never relay on a outside data. It's better to pass this data to the object as a method argument:

```
 __construct(array $post) {
     foreach (...) {

     }
 }

 new Abc($_POST);
```

And returning to your question... More strict validators are usually better, however it always depends on what you're trying to achieve. You could define a list of expected elements and throw an exception when some extra element is being found.

Comment: Either throw an exception when some extra data is being found, or... ignore POST if it does not have some data, as POST might come from another `<form/>` on the same page. That's what I usually do - `if ( !isset($_POST['button_name'], $_POST['some_field'], ...) ) { return; }`